# Can I revert previous commits on GitHub either through their website or GitHub for Windows without having to pull?

Tags: github

If I make a commit to a file in a repository on GitHub and I want to revert it, can I do this through GitHub for Windows without having to first pull the current version of the repository locally? The problem with that is that I don't want to update local files with what's in the repository. Alternatively, can that be done via GitHub's website? I want to do this via some GUI and not through terminal.